# Is there any way to get ADS in my Flash Air app without using SDK extensions?

Tags: flash, air, sdk, ads

Is there any way to get ADS in my Flash Air app without using SDK extensions?

Are there any websites witch makes it easy to implement ads in a Flash APP?

Answer (score 1):

http://lilili87222.github.com/admob-for-flash/

user can show all type of banner ad and full screen(interstitial advertising) ad of admob

user can show landscope and portrait advertising in actionscript 3 mobile application

user can set postion of ad

easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StageWebView` to display normal HTML ads (banners, etc).
Try [adMob](http://www.google.com/ads/admob/) as a provider.